# Get user privileges per table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

When I run query:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee = (select user)
```

This shows only those tables (with all privileges), which I (current user) created on this DB, There are lots of another tables (created by another users), where I can succesfully ran `UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands for example, though those tables are not shown by above query.

I though that query is way, to check user priveleges for each tables. but seems thats not quite  correct? please tell me where I'm wrong ?

Comment: You're probably missing privileges inherited from other roles (like `PUBLIC`)?